# set style in dynamically loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic

I want to convert:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>
```

Into loading it dynamically with javascript, my code so far is:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://www.example.com';
iframe.width = '0';
iframe.height = '0';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

But once that loads, a little box is visible, i tried adding:

```
iframe.style = 'visibility:hidden;display:none';
```

But that had no effect, does anyone know how to do this (without JQuery)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the frameborder to 0:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'http://www.example.com';
iframe.width = '0';
iframe.height = '0';
iframe.frameBorder = '0'; // Add this line
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```